# Connect Unix/Solaris with .NET using SSH

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unix, ssh

For my project I need to connect with remote Unix server from my local machine. I want to connect the machine using Visual Studio in the same manner as we can connect Java using SSHXCute JAR and be able to execute Unix command, upload file etc.
Please suggest a way to do the task in dot net c#

Comment: And what your question is? For SSH clients search google for ".NET SSH client"

Answer (score 0):

[A Secure Shell (SSH) library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11966/sharpSsh-A-Secure-Shell-SSH-library-for-NET)